# Trying to save information from different html pages into an array then display them in another html page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to make a fake clothing brand website and I want to get user inputs from what the user wants into a list and then display them in a cart html page.

The code for one of the selection pages is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title> Bison Brand Shirts </title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="bison_brand_logo.png" type="image/png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bison_brand_style.css">
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bison_brand.js"></script>

<div class="outer">
    <div class ="inner"> 
        <img src="bison_silo.png" alt="bison" width="122.857142857" height="80.5714285714">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>

<body>

    <h1 > shirts </h1>  
    
    <img src="bison_brand_light_grey_t-shirt.png" width="200px" height="200px">
    
    <p>price: $30<p>
    
    <label for="size">size:</label>
    <select name="product" id="product">
        <option value="shirt_small">small</option>
        <option value="shirt_medium">medium</option>
        <option value="shirt_large">large</option>
        <option value="shirt_xlarge">xlarge</option>
    </select>
        <span class="output"></span>
    <button onclick="addCart(); getCart()"> add to cart </button>
    <h2> <a href="bison_brand_home.html">home</a> <a href="bison_brand_cart.html">cart</a></h2>
    
</body>
</html>
```

My javascript code is this:

```
console.log("here");
var cart = [];
var input;
function addCart() {
        selectElement = document.querySelector('#product');     
        output = selectElement.value;
        console.log("cart:");
        cart.push(output);
        console.log(cart);
        localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
}

function getCart() {
        alert(cart);
}
```

My cart html code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title> Bison Brand Cart </title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="bison_brand_logo.png" type="image/png">
</head>
<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bison_brand.js" ></script>
<style>
    body{
        background: #E38F66;
    }
    h1{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 75px;
        font-family: "Courier New";
    }
    h2{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-family: "Courier New"; 
    }
</style>
<body onload="getCart()">
    <h1 > Cart </h1>    
    <h2> <a href="bison_brand_home.html">home</a></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Any tips or ideas would be great. I have never used PHP but am open to try it.

Comment: PHP is way to go bro, as in these e-commerce websites user data are never preferred to store as array in javascript, better use database (postgre/mysql/mongo) and store info there and fetch it.

Comment: What is your problem? Are you asking how to utilize localStorage to send JSON data from one page into the cart page? You've done half the work, now you just need to extract the JSON with the getItem function and present that data into the page. If you are wondering how to format the JSON, you probably want to go with an array of key value pairs, like [{"item": "crew neck", "price": 50, "size": "XL"}]. If you are wondering how to present that into the page, you probably want to look at how Javascript can influence the DOM.